# Compound interest formula $A= \frac{p((1+\frac rn)^{nt}-1)}{\frac rn} $

Tags: arithmetic, finance, word-problem

I am doing an MBA assignment and I have given this formula

$$A=\frac{p((1+\frac rn)^{nt}-1)}{\frac rn} $$

Is this formula correct? I have usually seen $A=p(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$

The specific problem is

"You make monthly payments of $500 into a retirement annuity that earns 4% compounded monthly. What is the value of your account after 10 years?  Round your answer to the nearest cent (two decimal places)."

Comment: It's always less than satisfactory to be handed a formula without any proof of why it is so, or what restrictions may apply to it's use... You could start to explore it by putting in small numbers to which you can work out what the answer should be...

Comment: When the payments are made, at the beginning or the end of the month each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $p(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$ is the compounded value of a single payment. The value in 10 years is the sum of all monthly payments, which is

$$A=\sum_{k=0}^{nt-1} p \left(1+\frac rn \right)^{k}=\frac{p((1+\frac rn)^{nt}-1)}{\frac rn}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Just to be certain, does this calculation look correct - P = 500, r = 0.04, t =10,
n=12,r/n = 0.003333333,1+r/n = 1.003333333, nt =120,(1+r/n)^nt =1.490832682,
(1+r/n)^nt-1 = 0.490832682, P((1+r/n)^nt-1)= 245.4163412,P((1+r/n)^nt-1)/(r/n) =73624.90236. Thus A = 73624.90236

Comment: @ManuChadha - correct